# ajax aspx example

Tags: ajax, asp.net

Can anyone provide a simple use of AJAX in a vb aspx page, so I can just reload a part of the page and not have to reload the entire web page?

Comment: You may want to provide more details. Are you using any client side libraries - jQuery, ASP.Net Ajax, etc.? The WebForms model makes it tough to render small bits of templated html unfortunately, but it can be done...

Answer (score 1):

[UpdatePanel example from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx) would be my suggestion for what you want.

Comment: I think I just threw up in my mouth a little bit.